# Writing to a remote file using Spring Integrations Sftp Streaming java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

How to write to a remote file using Spring integrations Sftp Streaming .I got some code using xml but I have to strictly use java configuration and I cant find any . I have to keep on appending some data to the file after some validation failure.So its not a one time write/transfer  but I have to maintain the connection with remote and keep on appending the file with error logs.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` `execute()` with a `SessionCallback` ...

```
SftpRemoteFileTemplate template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory);
PipedInputStream pipe = new PipedInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipe);
template.execute(s -> {
    s.write(pipe, "/foo/bar.log");
    return null;
});
```

Writing to the output stream (from another thread) will be piped to the input stream. Transfer will end when the stream is closed.

Comment: I mean, who else can answer this question better?

Comment: Sorry, for off-topic. It was rhetorical question, because you are the lead at Spring Integration project, so you probably know what you are talking about, but the answer is still not accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I want to write some logs as and when I get failure from some service call.So in this answer I can see only the folder where the log file would be present but how do I pass the log data from the code to a particular file ?

Comment: This writes to a file /foo/bar? It's not a directory it's a file. You said you want to append to the same file. If you want to append to different files you should use the append method. I changed the filename to `foo/bar.log` to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks A ton!It worked for me.Only change I did is , used append instead of write in order to append to the same file as write was not working i.e it was not appending to the same file.Thanks once again