# Spring Batch Java configuration - Writing to remote sftp xml file without local file

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

I have a requirement to write xml file to a sftp server in a Spring Batch application. Currently below code writes xml file to local file system using StaxEventItemWriter. I need to write directly to remote server instead of writing it to local and then moving to the sftp server. Referred this link ([Writing to a remote file using Spring Integrations Sftp Streaming java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630475/writing-to-a-remote-file-using-spring-integrations-sftp-streaming-java-configura)) but not sure how to write using StaxEventItemWriter/setup Resource object with remote file

```
public void write(List<? extends UserDTO> items) throws Exception {
    for(UserDTO item : items) {
        StaxEventItemWriter<UserDTO> staxWriter = getStaxEventItemWriter(item);
        staxWriter.write(Arrays.asList(item));
    }
}

private StaxEventItemWriter<UserDTO> getStaxEventItemWriter(UserDTO user) {

    String key = user.getDomain();      
    StaxEventItemWriter<UserDTO> writer = writers.get(key);
    if (writer == null) {enter code here
        writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
        try {
            UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("file:"+outputDir+"/"+key+"_"+fileName+".xml");
            writer.setResource(resource);
            writer.setRootTagName("customerSet");
            Jaxb2Marshaller UserMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
            UserMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(UserDTO.class);
            writer.setMarshaller(UserMarshaller);
            writer.setOverwriteOutput(Boolean.TRUE);
            writer.open(executionContext);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writers.put(key, writer);

    }
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `ftp:` instead of `file:` in your `UrlResource` definition? I'm referring to this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-implementations-urlresource.

Comment: UrlResource doesnt seem to support sftp

Answer (score -1):

You can probably try to use [SftpResource](https://github.com/chrisjs/sftp-resource) which is based on Spring Integration (similar to the solution in the link you shared) and use it in your `StaxEventItemWriter`.

Comment: Not sure how to implement SftpResource for StaxEventItemWriter as its implemented using ByteArrayResource for Reader which I have referred and implemented already to read a sftp file without downloading to the local system.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that `SftpResource` does not implement `org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource`. You actually need a similar class for a writable resource and use it with the `StaxEventItemWriter`.

Comment: Please point me to an example of WritableResource implementation for SftpResource if any as am not sure how to implement in this case for StaxEventItemWriter

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640028/5019386) in the link you have put in your question contains an example of code that you would use in your `WritableResource` implementation.

Comment: Do I need to implement getOutputStream() of WritableResource with the example code and how should it be invoked as StaxEventItemWriter just has setResource()?

Comment: Unluckily the link takes to a 404.